# XSLT parameter doesn't work

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Here is my java code, related to parameter:

```
    transformer.setParameter("limad","1234");
    transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(response.getOutputStream()));
```

My xslt has:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="limad"/>
    .... lots of stuff here...
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$limad"/>
                                </td>
    .... lots of stuff here...
</xsl:template>
```

My result is:
         <td></td>

Any ideas? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert with java, but if you are trying to pass parameters into an xslt, you need to put them outside template-match="/"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">


<!-- Imports -->
<xsl:import href="test.xslt"/>

<xsl:output method="html"
                  doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                  doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
                  indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>

 <!-- Parameters-->
<xsl:param name="limad"/>

<!-- Templates Match-->
<xsl:template match="/">
    .... lots of stuff here...
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="$limad"/>
                                </td>
    .... lots of stuff here...
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Correct answer. Parameters passed from the calling application always match global xsl:param declarations, not local parameters within a template.